# error handler of $http in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have an interceptor that does 

    `if (response.status !== 200){
       return $q.reject(response.statusText);
    }`

Then in my $http I do

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/something/parameters',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
  })
  .error(handleError);

function handleError(data) {
  console.log(data) //undefined?!
}
```

I got undefined.

But when I do `.error(function(data){ console.log(data) })` I got the response statusText, why? I have to split the function out because I have a service need to be triggered.

Comment: You're missing the "data" parameter in the $http call...

Comment: what should I do then? `.error(handleError(data));` ?

Comment: tried, nope. @Vi100 it doesn't matter.

Comment: check `response.data`

Answer (score 1):

Well, several things:

1) You are not providing the data parameter in your POST call. If you're not going to post anything, just use a get, or at least remove the ',' after the url parameter...

2) The structure you're using to make the $http call is DEPRECATED and is going to be removed in Angular 1.6 when it goes out from beta. Use this signature instead:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl',
  data: hereTheDataYouWantToPost
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

3) The response data is now attached to de response parameter... (that is: response.data) inside the callbacks.

See [Angular $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for a complete reference